# abort() has been called in project

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign data from one object to another and get me this error and choose an exception:
Unhandled exception at location 0x00007FFDCD79A839 in C ++ Project. Exe: Microsoft C ++ exception: std :: length_error in memory location 0x000000DDD04FA560.
Field.cpp

```
RectangleShape Field::getField() {
    return field;
}
```

Board.h

```
#pragma once
#include "DEFINIONS.h"
#include "Field.h"

class Board
{
private:
    int length{ 3 };
    int width{ 3 };
    int lengthBoard{ 0 };
    int widthBoard{ 0 };
    int a{ 0 };
    int b{ 0 };
    bool check{ true };
    RectangleShape ramka;
    Field** board;
public:
    Board(int length = 3, int width = 3, int margin_X = 0, int margin_Y = 0);
    void drawMap(RenderWindow& window);
};
```

Board.cpp

```
 Board::Board(int length, int width, int margin_X, int margin_Y) {
    this->length = length;
    this->width = width;
    ramka.setSize(Vector2f(800, 800));
    ramka.setFillColor(Color::Green);
    ramka.setOrigin(700, 700);
    ramka.setPosition(730, 730);

    board = new Field * [length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        board[i] = new Field[width];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *this->board[i] = Field();
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            *this->board[j] = Field();
            lengthBoard = length * board[0][0].getSize() + (length - 1) * board[0][0].getOdleglosc();
        }
    }

    while (check) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (lengthBoard > ramka.getSize().x&& lengthBoard > ramka.getSize().y) {
                    a = 0.95 * board[i][j].getSize();
                    b = board[i][j].getOdleglosc();
                    board[i][j].setSize(a);
                    board[i][j].setOdleglosc(b);
                    lengthBoard = length * board[0][j].getSize() + (length - 1) * board[0][j].getOdleglosc();
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                            if (lengthBoard < ramka.getSize().x && lengthBoard < ramka.getSize().y) {
                                a = 1.05 * board[i][j].getSize();
                                b = board[i][j].getOdleglosc();
                                board[i][j].setSize(a);
                                board[i][j].setOdleglosc(b);
                                lengthBoard = length * board[0][j].getSize() + (length - 1) * board[0][j].getOdleglosc();
                            }
                            else {
                                check = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!check)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (!check)
                break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            board[i][j] = Field(i, j, margin_X, margin_Y, a, b);
}

void Board::drawMap(RenderWindow& window) {

//  window.draw(ramka);
    scaleBoard(window);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            window.draw(board[i][j].getField());
            std::cout << board[i][j].getSize() << "---" << board[i][j].getOdleglosc() << std::endl;
            std::cout << a << "----------------" << b << std::endl;
        }
}
```

GameState.h

```
    Board tablica;
    void doIt(RenderWindow& window,int numer);      //metoda pozwalajaca zainicjowac całą tablice
    int game(RenderWindow& window, Event& event, Vector2f mouse, int numer);
};
```

GameState.cpp

```
 void GameState::gameload(RenderWindow& window, Event &event, int numer) {
    Board board(numer, numer);
    tablica.setA(board.getA());
    tablica.setB(board.getB());
    //tablica.setBoard(board.getBoard());
    tablica.setCheck(board.getCheck());
    tablica.setLength(board.getLength());
    tablica.setLengthBoard(board.getLengthBoard());
    tablica.setRamka(board.getRamka());
    tablica.setWidth(board.getWidth());
    tablica.setWidthBoard(board.getWidthBoard());
    loadBackground();
    window.draw(background);
    board.drawMap(window);
    drawPause(window);
    setTextureKrzyzyk();
    setTextureKolko();
    setTextureKolkoWin();
    setTextureKrzyzykWin();
}

void GameState::doIt(RenderWindow& window,int numer)
{
    loadBackground();
    window.draw(background);
    tablica.drawMap(window);
    drawPause(window);
    setTextureKrzyzyk();
    setTextureKolko();
    setTextureKolkoWin();
    setTextureKrzyzykWin();
}
int GameState::game(RenderWindow& window, Event& event, Vector2f mouse, int numer) {
    if (checker)
    {
        gameload(window, event, numer);
        checker = false;
    }
    doIt(window,numer);
        return pauseButton(mouse, event, STATE_GAME);
}
```

Comment: Now is the time to learn how to use your debugger. Run the program in the debugger, and let it catch the crash as it happens. Then you can find out where in your code it happens, and examine variables to see that their values are what are expected.

Comment: It's surprising you have all of this code, but have not attempted to debug it using the debugger.  No programmer that has written this much code would think that their code has no bugs, and thus would be ready to debug the code.

Comment: I debug, I know where the error is (when returning RectangleShape) and there are no these variables do not have the correct value, but why I don't know

Comment: You show a lot of code, but none that is "returning RectangleShape". Please learn how to create a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part) that replicates the problem, and edit your question to show it.

Comment: I've added so much code because the RectangleShape exception is returned when the drawBoard method is executed

Comment: `*this->board[i] = Field()` is equal to `this->board[i][0] = Field()`, and it isn't needed. When you allocate using `new[]` the `Field` objects are default-constructed automatically. Same with `*this->board[j] = Field()`

Comment: okey, after deleting this, I have the information that: "Reading incorrect data from board [i] and area may change